# Forward Clients to New Server using iptables

Tags: ubuntu, networking, domain-name-system, iptables, router

Clients are connected to a server `A` by connecting to the domain name address `www.example.com:4444`, where `www.example.com` resolves to the IP address of server `A`.

**Question:** In order to provide a seamless server upgrade, clients have to be transferred from server `A` to server `B` without disconnecting. The following iptables rules allow the clients to communicate with server `B` indirectly through `A`.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 4444 --to-destination 123.123.123.123 -j DNAT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 123.123.123.123 --dport 4444  -j MASQUERADE
```

However the clients still require server `A` in order to reach server `B`. Is there a way to tell the clients that the new server they should talk to is server `B` with ip address `123.123.123.123` and that they should go to that server IP address directly and no longer connect through `A`?

I'm assuming that changing the `A` records in the DNS and waiting for the changes to propagate to the client will require the client to restart (which is what we must avoid).

---

The server and client communicate via JSON messages over TCP, not HTTP.

Comment: Reduce the TTL for DNS records pertaining to A. Point A to B in the DNS. Setup a http proxy from A to B. Monitor connections on A. When there are none turn it off.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the A record of your DNS.

Normally you would lower the TTL of the record prior to the change to reduce how long other DNS servers will cache the "old" address for. You should lower the TTL at least  prior to when you actually change to the new server.

For example, if your TTL is normally 24 hours, you would reduce the TTL to 5 to 30 seconds 24 hours before you actually want to change. Then change the A record, and once you confirm everything is OK (ie, you don't need to revert back to the old server) you can increase your TTL back to normal.

Comment: The server does not do HTTP, but rather sends JSON data over TCP. Sorry, just updated OP.

Comment: Not sure how that is relevant. The same applies to any service, not just HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is normal HTTP, you don't have to restart the clients to apply DNS changes. The TTL simply needs to expire.
HTTP is a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), meaning that actual connections (sockets) normally aren't saved between requests ("page loads"), so "disconnect" means nothing.
The clients will lose the session (which is server-side), but this is inevitable (you are switching servers, after all).
You can test the change by modifying the clients' local [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) and seeing how they behave.